# Bootstrap CSS isn't being overridden by Custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, overriding

So I'm using bootstrap to make a navbar and used their example navbar as my foundation.
I fiddled with the bootstrap file to make it so that the navbar will collapse at 995px instead of 768px. Now because of that my navbar's button stays at the left side until the window size is below 768px.
I found that if I changed

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

to

```
@media (min-width: 995px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

then it works fine.

However I put

```
@media (min-width: 995px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

into a custom.css and loaded it after bootstrap.css and no change occurred. My custom.css didn't override the boostrap.css. I would like to refrain from changing the bootstrap.css.

This is what the navbar looks like right now
[image]

This is what it should look like
[image]

Comment: Try adding !important on the styles of the overwritten file.

Comment: I keep reading adding !important is bad practice. So I would prefer an answer without using important unless that is the absolute only way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the quick fix is adding `!important` to your custom styles.

Another way to fix this is to make your custom styles more specific. I'm talking about the selector. You should give the element an Id and call that in your custom styles.

This makes your custom styles more specific, and therefore take precedence. You can also increase the specificity by indicating the parents in the selector.

`header #yourNewId { ... }`  > `#yourNewId{ ... }`  > `.navbar-header{ ... }`

Comment: Is there really no way to just override the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: well you are overriding it, by being more specific with your selector. if you don't want to add an id you can try using `parent .navbar-header{ ... }` where parent is something like header or div

Answer (score 0):

Always apply latest rule with equal specificity selectors.
First, if not yet, place custom.css after bootstrap.css.

Then check media queries. If you just add

```
@media (min-width: 995px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

to custom, it can't override it between 768 and 994 in bootstrap.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Use something like it (change it to what you want):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 995px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The element is always floating left, so you won't be seeing any change. Never.